# Make a PATCH with complex Objects in C#

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core

I am setting up an REST Server in .net with a Patch Method. I want to make a Patch Request with an dynamic object. I don't know the fields which are to update. But this object can be a complex object.

I've already tried https://github.com/OmarMuscatello/SimplePatch#--global-mapping-functions but this library doesn't support complex objects.

For example: I've stored a object like

```
`{name: 'Herbert', age: 12}`
```

and my client send me via the http method patch `/api/person/{id}` this object

```
{name: 'hugo', Address: {zipcode: '4205', housenr: 5, street: 'Sunstone'}}
```

And I want to merge these to objects to one i can store. So i expect on object like

```
{name: 'hugo', age: 12, Address: {zipcode: '4205', housenr: 5, street: 'Sunstone'}}
```

my C# Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Address address {get; set;}
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
    public string housenr { get; set; }
    public Address street {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example request? What does this complex PATCH look like?

Comment: I have added an example. Is it understandable?

Comment: What is exactly  the `Patch` you said ,a HTTP request method or a method of operating data ? The logic of the three data in your example is not clear , could you explain more in detail? For the usage of  PATCH methods , you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this links: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sMAnO5d4OE

[How to create a Patch file for a web application using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230114/how-to-create-a-patch-file-for-a-web-application-using-asp-net/14251369)

**This is just example :**

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<string> Links { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow us to test patch operations against properties and arrays.

```
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class ContactsController : Controller
        {
            private Contact contact = new Contact
            {
                FirstName = "ex",
                LastName = "abc",
                Age = 30,
                Links = new List<string> { "http://example.io" }
            };

            [HttpPatch]
            public IActionResult Patch([FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Contact> patch)
            {
                var patched = contact.Copy();
                patch.ApplyTo(patched, ModelState);

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
                }

                var model = new
                {
                    original = contact,
                    patched = patched
                };

                return Ok(model);
            }
        }


    PATCH /api/contacts
    [
        {
          "op": "replace",
          "path": "/firstname",
          "value": "ac"
        },
        {
          "op": "replace",
          "path": "/age",
          "value": "29"
        },
    ]

{
    "original": {
        "FirstName": "ex",
        "LastName": "ac",
        "Age": 30,
        "Links": [
            "http://example.io"
        ]
    },
    "patched": {
        "FirstName": "ex",
        "LastName": "ac",
        "Age": 29,
        "Links": [
            "http://example.io"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already seen this example but i don't want to add foreach property an op and path value. It is easier possible? Like i have described in the question?

Comment: You are using the list property so that's why foreach property is must.